# Wechat - unable to send rich media messages more than 1

Tags: api, wechat

I hit the below request to display 2 articles but the api is giving error code - 45008. Although, it is working with 1 article

https://api.weixin.qq.com/cgi-bin/message/custom/send?access_token='My_Token'
Method: POST
Body:

```
{
    "touser": "OPENID",
    "msgtype": "news",
    "news": {
        "articles": [
            {
                "title": "Happy Day",
                "description": "Is Really A Happy Day"
            },
            {
               "title": "Happy",
                "description": "Is goof"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

**Error**:

```
{
    "errcode": 45008,
    "errmsg": "article size out of limit hint: [1kiZGA01844123]"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the Chinese docs it would seem that you can no longer send more than 1 article.

> 图文消息条数限制在1条以内，注意，如果图文数超过1，则将会返回错误码45008 *(Google Translate: The number of text messages is limited to one. Note that if the number of pictures exceeds 1, the error code 45008 will be returned.)*

https://mp.weixin.qq.com/wiki?t=resource/res_main&id=mp1421140547

Unfortunately it looks like the English documentation has not yet been updated to reflect this change.

Curious to know if anybody has found a workaround / new message type that could be used similarly instead?